# Built in method for testing either nil or empty array with assignment?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I can assign a variable, such that if `b` is nil, `c` will be assigned to `a`.

```
a = b || c
```

What's a good way to do the same for an array that has only nil elements?

This is my way:

```
a = b unless b.to_a.empty? 
a = c unless a.to_a.empty?
```

Comment: You may be interest in `compact` for arrays too.

Comment: Having an array containing only nil elements is suspicious. You might want to look at the code generating such an array. Usually, by a little bit of refactoring and use of `select` and `reject`, you can get arrays that are empty, or only contain valid values, making it easier to process at that point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a = b.all?(&:nil?) ? c : b`

Comment: Arup - From the OP: "What's a good way to do the same for an array that **has only nil elements?**"

Comment: How is my answer incorrect? I gave the OP exactly what he asked for.

Comment: How about `a = (b+c).compact`?

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest using `any?`:

```
b = [nil, nil]
c = [1, 2, 3]

b.any? #=> false
c.any? #=> true

a = [b, c].detect(&:any?)
a #=> [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: This should be the most performant of the three solutions, as it stops as soon as it finds a non-`nil` element. 
* Also, it can be written as `a = b.any? ? b : c`.
* HOWEVER, it does fail if there are elements with value `false`.

Answer (score 2):

Do as below :

```
a = b.compact.empty? ? c : b
```

[`Array#compact`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-compact) will be helpful method in this case, I think.